# The variable doesn't pass through Intent

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm feeling pretty sleepy and I might missed the mistake. The problem that  only 1 variable of 3 doesn't show in another screen when I pass variable through intent.

`intent.putExtra("title", model.title)`  and `intent.putExtra("city", model.city)` works but not `intent.putExtra("content", model.description)`

Here is my AdAdapter.class :

```
class AdAdapter(ads: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<AdModel?>) : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AdModel,
        AdAdapter.AdViewHolder>(ads) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AdViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_list,
                parent, false)
        return AdViewHolder(itemView)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AdViewHolder, position: Int, model: AdModel) {

        //holder.imageView.setImageURI(model.uri)
        holder.textView1.text = model.title;
        holder.textView2.text = model.city;
        holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener { view -> //Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"click on item: "+model.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            val intent = Intent(view.context, Details::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("title", model.title) // shows in another screen
            intent.putExtra("city", model.city) //shows in another screen
            intent.putExtra("content", model.description) // doesn't pass through
            view.context.startActivity(intent)
    }}

    class AdViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        //val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view)
        val textView1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_1)
        val textView2: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_2)
        val relativeLayout: RelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    }
}
```

And here is my Details.class :

```
class Details : AppCompatActivity() {
    var detail_title: TextView? = null
    var author_title: TextView? = null
    var detail_detail: TextView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)
        detail_title = findViewById<View>(R.id.detail_title) as TextView
        author_title = findViewById<View>(R.id.detail_city) as TextView
        detail_detail = findViewById<View>(R.id.detail_content) as TextView
        val intent = intent
        val title = intent.getStringExtra("title")
        val author = intent.getStringExtra("city")
        val description = intent.getStringExtra("content")
        detail_title!!.text = title
        author_title!!.text = author
        detail_detail!!.text = description
    }
}
```

Also here is an xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Details">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="682dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="93dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="93dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="196dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="260dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="260dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="516dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="445dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detail_title" />
```

Here is how put data in the Adapter.

```
class Main : Fragment() {
    var mbase: DatabaseReference? = null
    var adapter: AdAdapter? = null




    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    var list_recycler_view:RecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_recycler_view);
        mbase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val ads = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<AdModel>()
            .setQuery(mbase!!, AdModel::class.java)
            .build()
        adapter = AdAdapter(ads)
        list_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)
        list_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(activity))
        list_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter)





    }
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter!!.startListening()
    }

    // Function to tell the app to stop getting
    // data from database on stoping of the activity
    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        adapter!!.stopListening()
    }
```

Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. How do you understand that content does not pass to DetailsActivity? through debugging or UI? also what do you mean `does not show` it is empty or null or what? Maybe your model does not have a description at all.

Comment: @DmytroIvanov it doesn't display on a second screen , but the other variables are displayed on the second screen.

Comment: What if it does not exist in your model? Put a breakpoint and see the model has this property inside method `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: I added code of the model and what I received from the debbuger.

Comment: Also tried using other model variable (I used ```model.city```) to display and it didn't show the other variable either.

Comment: You did not understand me. I mean, how is creating those models? Show me code before, like setting adapter for recyclerview and creating models for showing.

Comment: You mean like how I'm storing data into the model from firebase? I added the code.

Comment: Could you add a statement `Log.i("info", model.description)` inside your setOnClickListener lamba expression? and show the result.

Comment: @DmytroIvanov I solved the problem. The problem was in the xml file and not on how I set the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
```

It looks like it's only 10dp wide, could that be why you're not seeing it? Or is it offscreen?

Comment: Yep, that solved the problem! Now I keep in mind on how I set the margins now.